# Java: Override a method from grandparent

Tags: java

I have an abstract class A, and an abstract class B inheriting A. 
Then, I have a class C(not abstract) that inherits B.

I need to override some methods declared abstract in A, and not implemented in B to be implemented in C.

But when I try to do this, and add an Override annotation on top of my method, it says its not valid as that method does not exist in the parent.

How can I do this?

Code with signatures:

```
public abstract class A {

abstract protected EntityType getEntityType();
abstract protected ActionResponse doProcessing();
}

public abstract class B extends A {
   @Override
   EntityType getEntityType() {
     ....
    ...
    }
}

public class C extends B {
     @Override
     ActionResponse doProcessing() {
     ...
     ..
    }
}
```

Comment: make sure the signature of the overridden method matches the overriding method. and make sure this method in class A is visible to class C

Comment: Its a valid scenario. Paste your relevant code.

Comment: I tried to put your words into code above to make it easier for others to follow.

Comment: Added skeleton of the code.

Answer (score 1):

`Access Modifier` of the Sub class can't weaker than it's `Super Class`. It is better to change the `Access Modifier` of the sub classes to `protected` from `default`

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth [says otherwise...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132285/java-methods-override-vs-abstract#comment19566511_14132285) It may just dependent on the version of Java. This may not work in version 1.5.

Comment: There was a typo in my code earlier, check it out now

Comment: you put weaker access modifier in your sub class did you check that

Answer (score 0):

A:

```
public abstract class A {
    public abstract D getClassD();
}
```

B:

```
public abstract class B extends A{
}
```

D:

```
public class D {
}
```

And C:

```
 public class C extends B {
    D d = new D();

    @Override
    public D getClassD() {
        return this.d;
    }
}
```

It's correct. You cannot create class C without override method getClassD().

Please add field and initialize it.
If you use  Eclipse you can change in setting that IDE should put @Override or not

Comment: This is what I did, it doesn't work. It says: : method does not override or implement a method from a supertype(after adding override annotation)

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario works just fine in JavaSE 1.7. What version of java are you using?

```
public abstract class A {
    protected abstract Integer getMyInt();
    protected abstract String getMyString(); 
}

public abstract class B extends A {
    @Override
    protected String getMyString(){
        return "The answer is";
    }
}

public class C extends B {
    @Override
    protected Integer getMyInt() {
        return 42;
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C c = new C();
        System.out.println(c.getMyString() + " " + c.getMyInt());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you could access the grandparent directly you would create a dependency on the implementation of the father, and this would violate encapsulation.